Как разместить строку над текстом?
Так получается текст под картинкой. Мне по заданию нужно расположить картинку под текстом.
@dp.message_handler(text='Купить')
async def get_buying_list(message):
    for number in range(1,5):
        with open(f'Tovary/{number}.jpg', 'rb') as img_number:
            await message.answer_photo(img_number, f'Название: Product{number} | Описание: описание {number} '
                                       f'| Цена: {number*100}')
        await message.answer("Выберите продукт для покупки:", reply_markup=by_kb)


Приведу пример на telebot, но принцип тот же и для aiogram:
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    # URL изображения
    photo_url = 'https://image.winudf.com/v2/image/Y29tLkxpdmVXYWxscGFwZXJzVUEuYXBwMDQ1N19zY3JlZW5zaG90c180Xzg3YmZlZDdm/screen-4.jpg?fakeurl=1&type=.jpg'

    # HTML-разметка Подпись\Изображение
    message_text = f'<a href="{photo_url}">&#8203;</a> Описание' # &#8203; или пробел между тегами "> <" 

    # Сообщение с HTML-разметкой
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=message_text, parse_mode='HTML')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)


